# Matrix representation of trivial Hamiltonian

Tags: condensed-matter, hamiltonian

I was reading Kitaev 2009 periodic table paper when I came across the following

"Let us define the trivial hamiltonian:"
$$
\hat{H}_{\text {triv }}=\sum_{j}\left(\hat{a}_{j}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_{j}-\frac{1}{2}\right)=\hat{H}_{Q}
$$
where
$$
Q=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & 1 & & & \\
-1 & 0 & & & \\
& & 0 & 1 & \\
& & -1 & 0 & \\
& & & & \ddots
\end{array}\right)
$$
Now I wonder what this $Q$ matrix is all about, since I think the Hamiltonian matrix should be a diagonal matrix with diagonal value being $1/2$.

Comment: He's rewriting the Hamiltonian in terms of Majorana fermions. The Majorana fermion Hamiltonian can be written as a matrix equation $\vec{c} Q \vec{c}^T$ where $\vec c$ is a vector of the Majorana fermions and $Q$ is the matrix you've written above. If this is still unclear, I can write a longer response.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the notation defined in this specific paper: what is $Q$ and what $H_Q$ means?

Regardless, since $Q$ is not the same as $H_Q$, it doesn't have to be diagonal simultaneously with the Hamiltonian. And while a Hamiltonian is diagonal in the representation of its eigenstates, it is certainly not the case in an arbitrary representation.